# Moving tasks to next sprint but burndown chart is empty

Tags: azure-devops

I have moved/reassigned tasks and their backlog items to a new sprint (current sprint), but the burndown chart is empty.

We are using the Scrum template

Looking over the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/sprints/sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops), I see Im to check the following
If your sprint burndown chart appears empty, check the following:

- Have you assigned tasks to the sprint associated with the chart?
- Have you assigned remaining work to the tasks assigned to the sprint?
- Are the parent work items of the tasks assigned to the same sprint? If
  not, the tasks may appear in another sprint associated with the
  parent item.

All the above have been set, but my burndown chart is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need also check the date configure.

One reason which can lead to this issue is the last update date of the work item does not within the time period of your burndown chart. You can check the **update date** of your work item and the **start date** of the burndown chart.

For example: If the update date of the work item is 2019/7/25, but the start date of the burn down chart is 2019/7/26. This work item will not be displayed in the burndown chart.

Additionally, you still need to check your **Burndown on** value selected:

[image]

Comment: I suppose I was referring to what appears to be a change of how one access the burndown chart.  Did the area at the top right of the sprint view change to no longer have the link for the chart?  I now see a tab added called "analytics".  Is this new?

Comment: @bitshift Yes, this is the new feature released in last sprint which deployed recently.

Comment: @bitshift You can view this change from our release note.

Answer (score 0):

The link for the simple burndown chart from the sprint view was removed during the day yesterday.  There is a problem report here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/666651/sprint-burn-down-charts-arent-appearing.html

There is some discussion in that link that the product group is considering restoring it temporarily until issues with the analytics burndown chart are fixed.

The original chart is still available via API call.  I wrote a simple user script for chrome to restore original functionality.  The version I wrote is for a single project as that's my need but would be extensible without too much effort if necessary.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Burndown Chart Extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "https://dev.azure.com/[collection]/[projectName]/_sprints/taskboard/*" ],
      "js": [ "burndown.user.js" ],
      "run_at":  "document_idle"
    }]
}
```

burndown.user.js:

```
function addJQuery(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.textContent = "window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

function main() {
    var jsInitTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (jQ('.vss-HubTileRegion span').length) {
            clearInterval(jsInitTimer);
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute('src', 'https://dev.azure.com/[collection]/[projectId]/[teamId]/_apis/work/iterations/[iterationId]/chartimages/burndown?width=120&height=38&counter=18')
            var anc = document.createElement('a');
            anc.setAttribute('href', 'https://dev.azure.com/[collection]/[projectId]/[teamId]/_apis/work/iterations/[iterationId]/chartimages/burndown?width=1400&height=1000&showDetails=true&counter=18')
            anc.append(img);
            jQ('.vss-HubTileRegion span').append(anc);
        }
    }, 500);
}

addJQuery(main);
```